# Mutable AI VSCode Extension adds .vscode/settings.json file every load

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I recently started using the Visual Studio Code extension [Mutable AI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mutable-ai.mutable-ai). It turned out to be useful alternative after Copilot became paid. But every time I open a folder, it creates `.vscode/settings.json` inside the folder with these contents

```json
{
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "diffEditor.codeLens": true
}
```

How do you prevent Mutable from creating this file every time VS Code loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it does that! Mutable creates this file because it requires those settings to work. I had the settings flipped, so every time I opened a folder, it would set them for me. Here's how to fix it:

1. Go to settings (<kbd>ctrl + ,</kbd>)
2. Search for each of those settings (tab completion, codelens), and set them to their respective options.
3. If those were the only settings in the `.vscode/settings.json` file, delete the file itself.
4. If you deleted the file and there's nothing else in the `.vscode` folder, delete the folder too.